# Trigger Procedure Not Showing Up In Staging/Production

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, database-trigger

So I have this trigger procedure in my structure.sql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dead_filter() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $dead_filter$
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.all_votes > 6 AND NEW.non_skip_votes/NEW.all_votes::float < 0.56) THEN
            NEW.dead := true;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$dead_filter$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER dead_filter AFTER UPDATE ON statements 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dead_filter();
```

And it works locally just fine, but for some reason it is showing up in my staging and production servers!

Both live on a heroku app, and both have

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

in their relevant config files.  What am I missing here?

```
select * from pg_trigger;
```

doesn't include my trigger on staging/production, but DOES locally, on development.

Is there something I need to run to have the structure.sql file re-read?  Backend is definitely my weak spot, so if there's something super obvious I should've known to do...odds are I didn't know to do it!

Thanks!

Comment: This can be silly question, but have you run migrations on your production database that actually adds this trigger?

Comment: Silly questions are the ones I am after!  As it turns out my ignorance was shining through - I was under the impression I could just add the trigger to my structure.sql (which was working with localhost) and it would just auto-magically work on staging and prod...Not the case!  I added a migration, and can now see it in staging's pg_trigger.  If you want to make your comment an answer I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in a comment, you need to create a migration that adds a trigger and run this migration on production as it is not automatic on Heroku. Also please note that `structure.sql` file will be regenerated after running migrations locally or task such as `rake db:schema:dump`. So you shouldn't edit this file manually.

Comment: Learn something new every day!  Thank you!

Comment: On the off chance you pick this up, Michal - I have my trigger on staging now, and it shows up in pg_trigger, but I'm still having no success with it actually firing, whether I manually UPDATE the table or use my app to create the appropriate number of entries...thoughts?